# Extend my network connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I live in a three floor brick house. My router is at the entrance on the ground floor. My office where I have my computers is one floor upper. I have both 2.4 and 5ghz enabled. On the ground floor I get a network speed of 190 mbps out of 200 which is really good. There is no easy way for me to bring a cable to the upper floor where I have my studio. Also the wifi is not as good there since the office is on the different side with the router. Currently I am using a Devolo dLAN 1200+ - Wifi Powerline to bring the internet to my office using the power socket. This is working ok but the problem is that I get a 40 mbps out of 200mpbs.

Is there a better way to bring the internet one floor upper without loosing so much in connection without a cable? Maybe a wifi repeater? Thank you

Comment: Power line adapters(depending on make/model) can be absolute garbage. This question has been answered here in many different ways. I found this by searching super user, and it's pretty much exactly how I would have answered it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what device(s) do I need to extend my wireless home network via creating a new wireless network (not using an extender)](https://superuser.com/questions/358794/what-devices-do-i-need-to-extend-my-wireless-home-network-via-creating-a-new-w)

Comment: Using dd-wrt you can either extend your current wireless network or make a separate SSID (network name) for the extended network. I would recommend using the same SSID and security settings